# How can i connect my android device (not emulator) to wamp server?

Tags: php, android, mysql, android-intent, device

I want to make an entry into my MySQL database. I am using WAMP server. I have successfully created database entry into my MySQL database using my Android emulator's app but I can't done it by using my external physical Android device. I'm using my IPv4 address (http://192.168.42.206/pankaj/v1) to connect with wamp server. So how can I connect my Android device (not emulator) to WAMP server?

Answer (score 0):

- Start Wamp Server;
- Click on the icon and select 'Put Online' option.

It should work now.